# Login worked locally but does not work online

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

I have a login page which made use of bootstrap modal box which worked fine when I tested it on wampserver but the money I moved it to cpanel, it kept on giving me login error message. i thought it was the database connection error at first but the connection is ok.

here is the html

```
<!-- modal login form -->
<div id="login-modal" class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="login-modal-container">
            <form id="login-form" role="form">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4>Login To Your Account </h4>
                    <div id="err-msg"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" class="form-control input-lg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-lg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div id="captcha"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery part

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#email').on('focus', function () {
        $('#email').removeClass('error');
    });

    $('#email').on('blur', function () {
        if ($('#email').val() == '') {
            $('#email').addClass('error');
        }
    });

    $('#password').on('focus', function () {
        $('#password').removeClass('error');
    });

    $('#password').on('blur', function () {
        if ($('#password').val() == '') {
            $('#password').addClass('error');
        }
    });

    $('#login-form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#err-msg').html('');
            var err = false;
            if ($('#email').val() == '') {
                $('#email').addClass('error');
                err = true;
            }
            if ($('#password').val() == '') {
                $('#password').addClass('error');
                err = true;
            }
            if (err == true) {
                return false;
            }

            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login.php',
            data: $('#login-form').serialize() + '&' + $('#login').attr('name') + '=' + $('#login').val(),
            success: function(status){
                if (status == true) {
                    $('#login').val('Signing in...');
                    setTimeout('window.location.href = "0/dashboard";',3000);
                } else {
                    $('#err-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Invalid email or password!</div>');
                    $('#email').val('');
                    $('#password').val('');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

the class function

```
<?php
class UserClass
{
    private $db;

    // constructor
    function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    function userLogin($email, $password)
    {
        //$password     = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 11));
        $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email = '" . $email. "' and user_password = '" . $password . "'");

        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            // success
            @session_start();
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['user_username'];
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $row['user_email'];
            //$_SESSION['pix'] = $row['pix'];
            //$_SESSION['jdate'] = $row['user_joindate '];
            //$_SESSION['lname'] = $row[' user_lastname '];
            //$_SESSION['fname'] = $row[' user_firstname '];

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // login fail
            return false;
        }

    }

    function userLogout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_email']);
        return;
    }

    function escapeString($str) {
        return $this->db->real_escape_string($str);
    }
}
?>
```

Lastly this

```
<?php
include_once('db/dbconnect.php');
require_once '../includes/functions.php';

if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $email = $con->escapeString($_POST['email']);
    $pwd = $con->escapeString($_POST['password']);
    $password   = encryptIt($pwd);
    echo $con->userLogin($email, $password);
}


?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: Are you sure you have the same users in the "cpanel" database as in your local db?

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: @addie, there was no error except for the fact that it was saying Invalid email or password! whereas the username and password supplied were both correct.

Comment: @teresko, if you truly go through the code you will see all input sanitized

Comment: post `db/dbconnect.php` ill try it in my host

Comment: @addie, <?php
// mysql connection
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'green_parrot';

$db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
if($db->connect_errno)
 die('Error ' . $this->db->connect_error);

include_once('UserClass.php');
$con = new UserClass($db);
?>

Comment: where you get `encryptIt` function?

Comment: @addie, from the function I declared: function encryptIt($value) {
  // The encodeKey MUST match the decodeKey
  $encodeKey = 'swGn@7q#5y0z%E4!C#5y@9Tx@';
  $encoded = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($encodeKey), $value, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($encodeKey))));
  return($encoded);
 }

Comment: the one you commented works better `password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 11));`